# Can I record video on Android device and encode it in h.264 (Baseline profile) on it?

Tags: android, android-camera, h.264, video-encoding, android-mediacodec

I need to determine how can I record video in Android device and encode it in h.264 Baseline profile in mp4 container. I can't find information about this because smartphone manufacturers usually don't show it. All I know is that Sony Z3 encodes all recorded video in H.264 High Profile (L3-L6), HTC One M8 - H.264 Baseline, Samsung Galaxy S3 - partially in High and Baseline.

Comment: You can query the CodecProfileLevel information out of http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps me:
http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/
I used this ready-made solution because I had problems with compiling ffmpeg libs with Cygwin64 and Android NDK on Windows 7.

Comment: am not able to understand hot to use it

Comment: You must use official [FFmpeg Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html).
it is a bit difficult, but there is no alternative.
For example:
`String[] cmdArray = {"-y", "-i", path, "-map", "0", "-c:v", "libx264", "-profile:v", "baseline", "-level", "3.0",
                    "-preset", "ultrafast", "-b:v", multipliedVideoBitRate, "-bufsize", multipliedVideoBitRate, "-c:a", "copy", "-b:a", AUDIO_BIT_RATE_STRING, output};                   `
`try {`
       `ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(context);`
       `ffmpeg.execute(cmdArray, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() { ... }`